# How to get seconds elapsed from a list of time strings in R?

Tags: r, time-series

I am new to playing with time on R and am stuck on a task. I have a list of time strings of the form "11:00:12 AM" i.e. "hour:minutes:seconds AM/PM" in chronological order. For each entry, I would like to obtain the seconds elapsed from the first time. For example, if the entries are "11:00:12 PM", "11:00:32 PM", "11:00:42 PM" I would like a list of the form  "0, 20, 30 ..."

Note that the strings do not contain date stamps - just time.

I tried using `parse_date_time` and `sapply` and got named numeric vectors which don't seem to recognize the time ordering. To illustrate, here's a sample code:

```
Time_list=c("11:00:12 PM", "11:00:32 PM", "11:00:42 PM", "12:00:12 AM", "12:00:32 AM", "12:00:42 AM")
new_list= sapply(Time_list, FUN=parse_date_time, orders='%I:%M:%S %p')
```

The obtained output is:

```
> new_list  
 11:00:12 PM  11:00:32 PM  11:00:42 PM  12:00:12 AM  12:00:32 AM  12:00:42 AM
-62167136388 -62167136368 -62167136358 -62167219188 -62167219168 -62167219158
```

As noticeable, it treats 12:00:12AM as a time **prior** to 11:00:42PM and I get the following output for time differences

```
> new_list[3]-new_list[4]
11:00:42 PM 
      82830 

> new_list[4]-new_list[3]
12:00:12 AM 
     -82830 

> difftime(new_list[3], new_list[4])
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(time1) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

and I am unsure of how to fix this. I realize I could manually add a date and change it to the next day at 12:00 AM, however, I have 100 such files that start at different times so this would be unfeasible, and I would prefer to automate this via code.

Any input is much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: `sapply` returns a matrix and this is the reason you get the values converged to numeric.  `parse_date_time(Time_list, orders='%I:%M:%S %p')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time_list` has just time there is no date in it. However, since we know that the time is in chronological order we can use `diff` to calculate the difference between consecutive time value and increment the date when the difference is negative.

We can then subtract the time with the first time to get the difference.

```
new_time_list <- as.POSIXct(Time_list, format = '%I:%M:%S %p', tz = 'GMT')
corrected_list <- new_time_list + c(0, cumsum(diff(new_time_list) < 0)) * 86400
corrected_list - corrected_list[1]

#Time differences in secs
#[1]    0   20   30 3600 3620 3630
```

Answer (score 1):

`parse_date_time` is vectorized.  There is no need to loop.  and if it is looped, use `lapply` instead of `sapply` because `sapply` returns a `matrix` and matrix can have a single class.  Here, the datetimes are internally stored as `double` and this results in coercing to `numeric` class.  Infact, we can use

```
library(data.table)
new_list <- as.ITime(Time_list)
difftime(new_list[3], new_list[4], unit = 'sec')
#Time difference of -3570 secs
```

Or for the entire vector

```
difftime(new_list[-1], new_list[-length(new_list)], unit = 'sec')
#Time differences in secs
#[1]   20   10 3570   20   10
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! That package didn't come up in my search and I shall try it out. This is exactly what I wanted. One question: Regarding the coercing to numeric class due to matrix having a single class - I am new to R and would like to learn such basics. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Merry If you check `?sapply`, the default option is `simplify`, which would return an array or matrix by default whereas `lapply` always returns list.

Comment: @Merry I know the issue when you are new to a particular language. Only way to learn it is to practice.  There is no easier option though.  Having said that, you should also know  whether the effort to put on learning a language is worth it i.e. do your research on job opportunties etc.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again!